# It's showing error while building the app

Tags: android, gradle

When I'm trying to build my app it's building process is stopped showing the following message in  logcat it's showing error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/lucasr/twowayview/BuildConfig.class

My build.gradle file is

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "community.infinity"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.adamstyrc.cookiecutter:cookie-cutter:1.0.2'
compile 'com.allattentionhere:fabulousfilter:0.0.3'
compile 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.6'
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
compile 'com.github.developer-shivam:FeaturedRecyclerView:1.0.0'
compile 'com.xujinyang.BiuEditText:library:1.4.1'
compile 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
compile 'gun0912.ted:tedbottompicker:1.0.12'
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.2'
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3.1'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:layouts:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: You are using two different versions of com.android.support:design

Comment: And also com.android.support:appcompat

Comment: Even after removing different versions the errors are same@CagriYalcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **SNAPSHOT** version :

compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'

compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:layouts:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'

and the **STABLE** version both at the same time

compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'

Try removing any of them. You should only use one at a time.

Visit:
https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view